# Vector space and Dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'm struggling with this problem:

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and let there be $l_1,l_2 \in V^*$.

I need to show that if $l_1(x)l_2(x)=0$ for every $x \in V$ then at least one of $l_1,l_2$ is 0.

Comment: The condition translates to $V = \ker l_1 \cup \ker l_2$. What do you know about the union of subspaces? When is it a subspace?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $l_1(v)\neq 0$ and $l_2(w)\neq 0$.  Then think about $l_1(v+w)l_2(v+w)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt after taking your note:
Let us take $v,w \in W$ such that:
$l_1(v) \neq 0$ and $l_2(w) \neq 0$

Note that since $l_1(v)$ and $l_2(v)$ are elements of a field, and since $l_1(v)l_2(v) = 0$ we get that $l_2(v) = 0$, similarly $l_1(w) = 0$.

Now $l_1(v+w)l_2(v+w) = (l_1(v)+l_1(w))(l_2(v)+l_2(w)) = l_1(v)l_2(v) + l_1(v)l_2(w) + l_1(w)l_2(v) + l_1(w)l_2(w)$.

But:
$l_1(w)l_2(v) = l_1(w)l_2(w) = l_1(v)l_1(w) = 0$

So finally we get $l_1(v)l_2(w) = 0$, but this is a contradiction. So either $l_1$ or $l_2$ are $0$.

I would like to know if this solution is correct.

Thanks!